# Configuración de fechas en PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero ingresar las fechas de agregado y entregado de un préstamo, pero tengo el código de tal forma que me pone la fecha del día que subo el préstamo y no la que yo pongo en el formato.

```
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $ID=$row['ID'];
    $Nombre=$row['Nombre'];
    $equipo=$row['equipo'];
    $Cargo=$row['Cargo'];
    $agregado= date('Y/m/d', strtotime($row['agregado']));
    $entregado= date('Y/m/d', strtotime($row['entregado']));

?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: tu problema es el formato? por favor muestra que formato obtienes y que formato quieres.

Comment: no el formato no quiero que me muestre las fechas que pongo y no la fecha de hoy

Comment: entonces? por favor explica cual es el problema, el resultado que quieres obtener, y el que recibes.

Comment: ok haber tengo el codigo de agregado y entregadi que son las fechas donde se agrega el prestamo y donde se entrega el prestamo pero al ingresar las fechasasi yo las ponga en 50 años me da las fechas de hoy 12/09/17 y no quiero eso jjaa gracias por contestar

Comment: en tu base de datos las fechas estan bien? como estas poniendo las fechas?

Comment: si la bse de datos esta bien

Comment: de tipo de nombre todo esta bien en la base de datos

Comment: vas a tener que mostrar la consulta entonces, y como muestras los datos.. en algun lado estas repitiendo valores.. tambien por lo que veo, estas guardando en variables el resultado de un while, y por lo tanto, solo vas a guardar los ultimos valores siempre

Comment: no es que se me esten duplicando lo que pasa es que en las 2 tengo la misma consulta pero diferente variable y por eso me muestra lo mismo porque ya mire y no se me esta duplicando nada

Comment: por cierto como hago para subir la consulta porque soy nuevo aqui

Comment: usa el boton [edit] para agregar toda la informacion que haga falta. no entiendo eso que dices de que en las dos tienes la misma consulta. las dos que?

Comment: ¿En la base de datos las columnas `agregado` y `entregado` son del tipo `datetime`? ¿Seguro que están almacenadas correctamente las fechas? ¿Puedes mostrar por pantalla las fechas correctamente, como, según tú deberían mostrarse?